# How to Export Multiple Cross Tables from Tableau Server into Excel

Tags: tableau-api

I have tableau server 2018.2 version but How to Export Multiple Cross Tables from Tableau Server into Excel

Comment: You can use the "Export All" extension: https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/products/25

Answer (score 2):

As per my understaning, it is still not possible to download multiple sheets from a published workbook. The user has to download one at a time.

There is even an idea created to promote this feature: [Tableau Community Forums > Ideas > Ability To Export Whole Workbook To Excel Similar To The PDF Function](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1398)

One workaround is to create a new sheet with all the data you need, in the format and order you need. There is an example here: [Exporting CSV Made Simple](https://public.tableau.com/s/blog/2014/04/exporting-csv-made-simple)